# How recovery wrong updates in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

I update a table, but my query clear all columms, can I roll back this updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a recent backup & binlog is active, there's a chance, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/point-in-time-recovery.html If not. it's a lesson learned....